# Can I simply use delegate even though it may not be required?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Can I simply use delegate even though it may not be required?

Comment: I think you mean `BeginInvoke`

Comment: I would look in to consolidating/refactoring in to one update method and invoke only once (dependent on if Control.InvokeRequired).

Comment: I don't understand the question. @SLaks, Invoke is also an option for invoking back onto the UI thread.

Comment: Could you be more clear?  What do you mean by *delegate method*?  Do you simply mean invoking a delegate?  If so, how would that address cross-threading?  Do you want to pass the method as a delegate through another method that does the if/else?

Comment: @Peter: I think they are referring to delegating in regards to the [BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3.aspx) method [see example on page] (keeping the UI and processing thread safe).

Comment: peter : i have added  the example code ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `Control.Invoke`, you don't need to check `InvokeRequired`, it checks it for you.

`Control.BeginInvoke` from the same thread is useful at times, it puts the call on the end of the message queue instead of making it immediately.

It's really not clear enough what you're doing to give specific advice.

---

Looking at your sample code, this is all you need:

```
WirelessGreenLight.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(redGreenLight));
```

or, if you can't change the caller:

```
public void redGreenLight()
{
    WirelessGreenLight.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(redGreenLightImpl));
}

private void redGreenLightImpl()
{
    // real work done here
}
```

Comment: thanks Ben , I apologize for being persistent , but I owuld need to invoke WirelessRedLight,MobileRedLight,MobileGrenLight too .. ie any of the 4 controls ... I was wanting to know if i could avoid such a long multiple ifs case ..

Comment: @HelloWorld_Always: No `if`s.  `redGreenLight` always uses `Invoke`, `redGreenLightImpl` needs no `Invoke` since it runs completely on the UI thread.